# Flutter - [Firebase] Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Don't know why I am getting this mail, I never used Firebase Database in my flutter project,

[image: FireBase mail]

After clicking on the hyperlink it redirects to this code

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Firebase has an option to revert changes. As you can see, that's version 2, so... someone made a change on those rules. If that wasn't you, change your password and add 2FA.

Comment: @mariano-zorrilla, the rules_version = '2'; actually refers to the version of Firebase Security rules you are using, and does not necessarily indicate that someone else has made a change on the rules ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#security_rules_version_2)).

Comment: You will need to learn how to use security rule to express the security requirements of your app.  A full discussion of that is off topic for Stack Overflow.  Start with the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: @Lunke what I was trying to say is that someone clearly made a change there.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not intend to to use Cloud Firestore Database at all in your project, I'd suggest turning off all read/writes. That will also stop the email-reminders of the insecure rules.

Simply change the `allow read, write: if true;` to `allow read, write: if false;`

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the same rule for my project, but still getting same mails

Comment: Hello, for this issue I would suggest to reach out their [support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) so that they can get further help while eliminating this issues. I believe they are the best option to get help on this.